# Sails: delete all elements and add new doesn't work correctly!! :(

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm trying a do a simple way: delete all elements of a collect and after insert the news.

I have a main collection `User` that have a collection `Awards` as Foreign Key:

```
award    : collection: 'Award'
```

In `Awards` collection I have a method like this:

```
updateAwards: (awards, cb) ->
      @award.remove award.id for award in @award
      @award.add award for award in awards
      @save(cb)
```

Simply doesn't work correctly! I don't know if is a callback problem.

When I call the method in first time the collection is empty and inserted the elements. If is empty and insert 2 elements => 2 elements in total. It's Ok.

But when I call the function again in another separate request for insert another two elements:

```
[ mocha test ]
 expected: 2
 actual  : 4
```

The worst part is if I checked the `localDiskDb` file I have 6 elements. wat?

```
"user": [
      {
        "email": "user1@sailor.com",
        "username": "user1",
        "picture": "assets/images/default.png",
        "rol": "user",
        "label": "Kiko Beats",
        "online": true,
        "summary": "Hello, this is my public profile and this is a generic summary information.",
        "country": "Internet, Worldwide.",
        "createdAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.077Z",
        "updatedAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.875Z",
        "id": 1
      }
    ],
    "award": [
      {
        "title": "IV Spanish Championship",
        "year": "2010",
        "description": "national event",
        "createdAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.666Z",
        "updatedAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.666Z",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "title": "Zombeats Summer Battle",
        "year": "2011",
        "description": "the best event of the summer",
        "createdAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.668Z",
        "updatedAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.668Z",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "description": "national event",
        "title": "IV Spanish Championship",
        "year": "2010",
        "createdAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.880Z",
        "updatedAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.880Z",
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "description": "the best event of the summer",
        "title": "Zombeats Summer Battle",
        "year": "2011",
        "createdAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.881Z",
        "updatedAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.881Z",
        "id": 4
      },
      {
        "title": "IV Spanish Championship",
        "year": "2010",
        "description": "national event",
        "createdAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.900Z",
        "updatedAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.900Z",
        "id": 5
      },
      {
        "title": "Zombeats Summer Battle",
        "year": "2011",
        "description": "the best event of the summer",
        "createdAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.902Z",
        "updatedAt": "2014-11-07T19:25:29.902Z",
        "id": 6
      }
    ]
```

The question is...**Why?** And what is necessary to do for work correctly?

The main user method for update the profile:

```
async.waterfall [
          (cb) ->
            User.update(user.id, user).exec (err, user) -> cb err, user
          (user, cb) ->
            # because update doesnt support populate...
            User.findOne(user.id).populate('award').populate('contact').exec (err, user) -> cb err, user
          (user, cb) ->
            user.updateAwards award, (err) -> cb err
          (cb) ->
            # ensure that recover the last version of the user....
            User.findOne(user.id).populate('award').populate('contact').exec (err, user) -> cb err, user
        ], (err, user) ->
          return res.negotiate(err)  if err
          user = params.user unless user?
          res.ok([user, user.award])
```

If you need to check any part of the code all is in Github:

controller => 
https://github.com/Zombeats/backend/blob/master/api/controllers/ProfileController.coffee
award => 
https://github.com/Zombeats/backend/blob/master/api/models/Award.coffee